# Does XML data always survive a round-trip through DataSet.ReadXML and DataSet.WriteXML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

I have been arguing with a colleague that XML content will not survive a round-trip through XML file -> DataSet.ReadXML -> DataSet -> DataSet.WriteXML -> XML.

The closest question I have found to date is:
[C#: How does DataSet.readXML( “filepath” ) work with my XML file that has objects within objects within objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241320/c-how-does-dataset-readxml-filepath-work-with-my-xml-file-that-has-object)

Specifically, does:

```
<root>
  <a>
    1
    <b>
      2
    </b>
    <b>
      3
    </b>
    4
  </a>
</root>
```

... when read into a DataSet using DataSet.ReadXML and then written out immediately with DataSet.XML into a new file will lose the leading '1' and the trailing '4' in the resultant XML file.

I have a VS2015 project wherein the leading '1' and trailing '4' are lost in the round-trip from XML->DataSet->XML.  The projects have unit tests showing cases where the XML does and does not survive the round-trip here:https://bitbucket.org/rchfreytag/testdataset

I'm very interested in hearing how I might be wrong even if only in edge cases.  Thanks!

Comment: The DataSet Read uses following tags 1) DataSet name 2) DataTable name 3) Column names 4) Data for each row.  When you have more than 4 nested tags additional DataTable are created which make it hard to parse the results.  It will survive the round-trip intact if the number of tags is less than 4 and you write the data including the schema.

Comment: What I think happens if that if the data at each level that is NOT a leaf is not just XML tags then that data is lost and doesn't make the round-trip.  I've demonstrated that in the project.  What I guess I'd like to know is if there is a way around this problem or if in some way I am 'doing it wrong?'

Comment: The is why is said you MUST use the schema when writing.   Leading ones one make a difference if you have a string or it is determining the size of the integer (byte, Int16, Int32, Int64, UInt16, Uint32, UInt64).  If you aren't using the correct TYPE then of course you are going to have issues.